# Facebook long-lived token expires after a few days

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, token

When i try to request a long-lived access token from the facebook api it gives back a token and when i test the token in the debugger it says it will never expire, a few hours / a day later i can't make any calls with the token anymore. It suddenly says:

"Any of the pages_read_engagement, pages_manage_metadata, pages_read_user_content, pages_manage_ads, pages_show_list or pages_messaging permission(s) must be granted before impersonating a user's page."

This is how i request the long lived token:

```
        $client = new Client([
        'base_uri' => 'https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/me/accounts? 
        fields=picture,category_list,name,access_token&access_token=' . $token,
        'timeout' => 2.0,
        ]);
```

Am i doing something wrong here? Does anyone else have this problem?

(Edit) - The problem occurs when i connect a second time from another website, it seems like when i connect a second site the first token gets disconnected?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _"when i connect a second time from another website"_?

Comment: "Do not use the same long-lived tokens on more than one web client" documentation mentioned this. 

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/refreshing#:~:text=Make%20this%20call%20from%20your%20server%2C%20not%20a%20client.

Comment: You need to do the oAuth process again for each user/website. I'm guessing you're regenerating (thus killing the original one) the access token instead of making a new one.